# One page scrolling website - but how to disable scrolling until an animation has complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have built a one page application, that has different position fixed sections that become hidden/shown - after a particular number of scrolls -- in each section when it becomes current -- css3 animations occur -- but as a requirement I need to disable scrolling until the animations have finished --- so when the user hits a section, disable their ability to transition to a new slide - disable/lock scroll until the animation has had time to complete --- otherwise half the elements fade and then blick out of existence.

-- if I use something like a class appended to the body - to overlow: hidden it would jar

-- do I remove scroll listeners and re-append them again? I am concerned that this will cause a malfunction in the ux -- maybe instead of scrollTo(0,0) -- fix it on the current slide scroll to pause their experience until the animations complete?

```
function noScroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

// add listener to disable scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', noScroll);

// Remove listener to re-enable scroll
window.removeEventListener('scroll', noScroll);
```

Answer (score 3):

with css  on body :

```
.noScroll {  overflow: hidden !important; }
```

JS:

```
document.body.classList.add('noScoll')
document.body.classList.remove('noScoll')
```

[edit] to respond to the legitimate concerns of `The Old County`

here is the part of code to add so that the page stays in the same place with or without the scroll bars:

```
const Remove_ScrollBars =_=>
  {
  let xLeft = document.body.scrollLeft
    , yTop  = document.body.scrollTop

  document.body.classList.add('noScroll')

  document.body.scrollLeft = xLeft
  document.body.scrollTop  = yTop
  }

const Return_ScrollBars =_=>
  {
  let xLeft = document.body.scrollLeft
    , yTop  = document.body.scrollTop

  document.body.classList.remove('noScroll')

  document.body.scrollLeft = xLeft
  document.body.scrollTop  = yTop
  }
```

**Demo 1:**

```js
const Remove_ScrollBars =_=>
  {
  let xLeft = document.body.scrollLeft
    , yTop  = document.body.scrollTop

  document.body.classList.add('noScroll')

  document.body.scrollLeft = xLeft
  document.body.scrollTop  = yTop
  }

const Return_ScrollBars =_=>
  {
  let xLeft = document.body.scrollLeft
    , yTop  = document.body.scrollTop

  document.body.classList.remove('noScroll')

  document.body.scrollLeft = xLeft
  document.body.scrollTop  = yTop
  }


noScrollBar.onclick = Remove_ScrollBars
ScrollBar.onclick   = Return_ScrollBars
```

```css
.noScroll {
  overflow: hidden !important;
 }
 p { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc </p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  <button id="noScrollBar">Scroll Bar Off </button> </p>
  <p>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   <button id="ScrollBar"> Scroll Bar On </button> </p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
```

[edit: 2]
OK, as you insist, I looked a little more on the type of answer you are looking for (keep the scroll bars but make them innactive)
So here is a new way to do it, I hope what will be the good?

```
var WindowPos = { x:window.scrollX, y:window.scrollY, fix : false }

const FixScroll = bool => WindowPos.fix = bool

window.onscroll =_=>{
  if (WindowPos.fix) window.scrollTo(WindowPos.x, WindowPos.y)
  else {
    WindowPos.x = window.scrollX
    WindowPos.y = window.scrollY
  }
}
```

**Demo 2:**

```js
var WindowPos = { x:window.scrollX, y:window.scrollY, fix : false }

const FixScroll = bool => WindowPos.fix = bool

window.onscroll =_=>{
  if (WindowPos.fix) window.scrollTo(WindowPos.x, WindowPos.y)
  else {
    WindowPos.x = window.scrollX
    WindowPos.y = window.scrollY
  }
}

fixBars.onclick =_=>{
  fixBars.innerText = FixScroll( !WindowPos.fix ) ? 'Set Scroll Bar On' : 'Set Scroll Bar Off'
}
```

```css
p { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc </p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>_ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _   <button id="fixBars">Set Scroll Bar Off</button>  </p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>aa</p>
  <p>bb</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
  <p>cc</p>
  <p>dd</p>
```

Comment: You've got typo `Document.boby`

Comment: --but wouldn't that just hide the bar as opposed to stopping them from scrolling -- it may jar the experience cause the screen width would change?

Comment: its part of the same problem though --- isn't there another way to pause the scrolling than do an overflow hidden ? to avoid it being a jarring experience where the screen shifts

Comment: @TheOldCounty  I have added a sample code to show that.

Comment: still jars -- leftX is always 0

Comment: bulk of the pages are positioned fixed

Comment: is there just a way to disable the scroll? grey it out

Comment: @TheOldCounty I made a new one, see demo 2. -> expect you validate my answer this time ? (as I need reputation points for job research...)

Comment: I think I tried something like this earlier -- it caused a malfunction on my navigation which skips the sections. I will check your solution soon

Comment: its more like the the malfunction causes the page to snap back and forth ---  you load the page - you can use the navigation to jump to a section. Or you can scroll to the section --- each section has css3 animations -- and they are unhappy with the current functionality where as they scroll quick -- the animations start, but don't have time to finish -- so they want the scroll to be disabled on each slide until the animations finish. There is also a master/slave relationship between the navigation and the scrolling onto a section -- so each controls the other kind of

Comment: Example -- its using css3 - so the animations start after the section is given the current class.

Comment: https://codepen.io/iblamefish/pen/pPbXGJ  --- a section would contain different elements and different animations -- that get invoked when its parent class gets changed to current ---

Comment: I think they would want it - so the elements fadein, fadeout - controlled by the scroll itself

Comment: I you on codementor - I could maybe repo the current base of the code and assign it to you to refactor the animation core parts of the application. Each slide has 3 key pieces that animate with css - but they are delayed/staged a little via json --- so animation classes will be appended to the img, then text, then 1 or more svg images -- at this stage so they just fade in... but they wanted other transitions like slideup/slideout but these have been removed. -- So ideally I think they want the items to animate in based on the speed of the scroll and reverse if the user scrolls up.

Comment: this may work but needs stabilization -- this offers a scrollable navigation control-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916705/gradual-fadein-fadeout-based-on-the-scroll @MisterJojo